# Google recaptcha v3 , invalid domain on loaded via iframe srcdoc

Tags: jquery, iframe, recaptcha

having to implement google recaptcha v3 if captcha is used on document loaded via iframe srcdoc

ex
example1.com have implement recaptca v3 which is working fine when using direct url example1.com.

if we load example1.com to example.com via below script

```
<script>
$(()=>{
    $.get('example1.com').then((html)=>{
       var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
       iframe.srcdoc = html;
       document.querySelector("body").appendChild(iframe);
    })
});
</script>
```

Also Have Added both domain to google recaptcha v3 domain listing.